# How long is temporary table available in Sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

In my android app I create a temporary table to make some joins on it.

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE pair (a INTEGER, b INTEGER);")
```

Could you tell me for how long time it's available? It seems that if I restart app it's gone but without restart it seems to be in database but for how long time?

All I found in docs that it's created in temp database.

> If the "TEMP" or "TEMPORARY" keyword occurs between the "CREATE" and "TABLE" then the new table is created in the temp database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The table will be local to the SQlite session, this means it is available as long as the `db` object is not reinitialized.

This fits well with the idea, that temporary tables should be seen only in the context, in which they were created: Two different instances of a DB session can have temporary tables **with the same name**, that are completly seperate and don't influence each other.